# Create a XSLT sheet from a XSL document? Not working? Done both the XLT doc and XLS Stylesheet

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Hello I am trying to put my XML document elements into a table format using the XSLT style sheet approach.

XML Document

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="Assignment2.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<cars orderid="199564"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Assignment1.xsd">
 <make>Chevy</make>
 <model>Colorado</model>
 <year>2017</year>
 <color>Silver</color>
 <engine>
  <number_of_cylinders>6</number_of_cylinders>
  <fuel_system>fuel injected</fuel_system>
 </engine>
 <number_of_doors>4</number_of_doors>
 <transmission_type>automatic</transmission_type>
 <accessories>
  <number_of_cylinders>8</number_of_cylinders>
  <fuel_system>fuel injected</fuel_system>
 </accessories>
</cars>
```

XLS Stylesheet(which contains the table format)

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2> Car Information </h2>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th> Make</th>
<th> Model> </th>
<th> Year </th>
<th> Color </th>
<th> No. of Cylinders </th>
<th> Fuel_System </th>
<th> Number of Doors </th>
<th> Transmission Type </th>
</tr>

<xsl:for-each select="cars">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="make"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="model"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="color"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="engine/number_of_cylinders"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="engine/fuel system"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="number_of_doors"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="transmission_type"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I watched this Youtube video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BujLy71JY1k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic0j3.png) over how to create XSLT in under 5 mins. I seen where the guy linked the XLS stylesheet file to the XML within the XML file itself. At first I thought I missed this part so I went back and tried it and it did't fixes the problem. I could be wrong on this but I believe both my XML Document and XLS file are both formatted correct and done right. What step or steps am I missing here??

P.S. I don't think it makes much of a difference but I have both the XLS stylesheet file and the XML document file in the same directory on my desktop.

When I try to load the XML file I keep getting this error message[XML Error loading stylesheet: X Path parse failure: operator expected message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic0j3.png)

Location of the files path =(C:\Users\Drake\Desktop\Exercise 7.4)

[Location of the XML and XLS Stylesheet file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s4E6.png)

Thank you for your feedback Drake!

Comment: I recommend using http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ to test your XSLT, as this will give you better error messages. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUp for you case, where it shows the actual line number in error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="engine/fuel system"/></td>
```

with

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="engine/fuel_system"/></td>
```

Comment: Awesome!!:) Thank you so much! You definitely have a good eye my friend!